# Python selecting from a dictionary using a portion of a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataset as a dictionary, where the keys have two bits of useful information: AAA_B-B : value. The A's and B's repeat across different combinations (4x4, 16 combinations).

I'm trying to create a list of the values associated with the different sets and plot the values, e.g, B-B1, B-B2, etc., so I'm trying to select based off a portion of a key. This is what I have so far:

```
for fileKey in photon_means.keys():
    pm_30 = []
    pm_35 = []
    pm_40 = []
    pm_45 = []

    for k in sorted(photon_means[fileKey].keys()):
        pm_30.append(photon_means[fileKey[4:7]['3-0']][k])
```

This returns a TypeError, that string indicies must be integers. Removing the quotes gets me "string index out of range" If I change the list append to:

```
pm_30.append(photon_means[fileKey[4:7]]['3-0'])
```

I get a KeyError for any of the values that do not have this key type (e.g, 3-5)
Any help would be appreciated!

edits: 
The dataset is an instrument calibration. The two keys indicate instrument settings. It is a set of nested dictionaries of the structure: 
{AAA_B-B: {Flow1: value}, {flow2: value}, {flow3: value}}

I have some working code, to plot all values across all dictionaries, which looks like this:

```
def calib(photon_means, conc_ppb):
    markers = {"600":"v", "650":"o", "700":"*", "750":"s"}
    colours = {"3-0":"r", "3-5":"m", "4-0":"g", "4-5":"b"}

    pyplt.clf()
    for fileKey in photon_means.keys():
        pm = []
        ppb = []
        for k in sorted(photon_means[fileKey].keys()):
            #pyplt.scatter([conc_ppb[fileKey][k]],[photon_means[fileKey][k]])
            pm.append(photon_means[fileKey][k])
            ppb.append(conc_ppb[fileKey][k])
        pyplt.plot(ppb,pm,label=fileKey, color=colours[fileKey[4:7]], marker=markers[fileKey[0:3]], ms=10.0)
```

I am ultimately looking to build 4 plots, sorted by setting B-B1, B-B2, B-B3, and B-B4.

Comment: Add more details of the file content and be more specific what you want e.g. SEVERAL example of from this i want this

Comment: Why not use a list of dictionaries, so then you wouldn't have to deal with subkeys?

Comment: There is no such thing in the dictionary as photon_means[fileKey[4:7]['3-0']], just photon_means[fileKey], assuming photon_means is the dictionary.  I don't understand your question either, so add some input/dictionary values, and expected output.